# Deleted Virtual table in SQL Server is empty ON Delete trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to invoke an `ON Delete` trigger event, but when I try to select row from the `Deleted` table, it is empty.

Is there any other way to get Id of row on which delete event has fired?

Code:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER TRIGGER [audit] 
   ON  [dbo].[S_PARTY] 
   FOR DELETE
AS 
    -- Insert statements for trigger here
  DECLARE @id nvarchar(50)
  SET @id = (Select ROW_ID from deleted )

  BEGIN

 -- Insert statements for trigger here

INSERT INTO [dbo].[S_AMF_AUDIT_ITEM] (ROW_ID)   
    VALUES (@id);

END
```

When trigger fires on this, I am getting error as `S_AMF_AUDIT_ITEM` doesn't allow null values. So can you please help me this to get Id of table on which delete command executes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger is broken.

It doesn't take into account that the `DELETE` statement might affect zero or more than one rows.

The issue with `NULL` could occur for the statement `DELETE FROM [dbo].[S_PARTY] WHERE 1 = 0`.

A fixed version would be

```
ALTER TRIGGER [audit]
ON [dbo].[S_PARTY]
FOR DELETE
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO [dbo].[S_AMF_AUDIT_ITEM]
                  (ROW_ID)
      SELECT ROW_ID
      FROM   deleted;
  END
```

Comment: worked!! .. but I still don't understand why SET @id = (Select ROW_ID from deleted ) doesn't set value. I am making sure that I delete only one row at a time. and Id exists on S_PARTY table from where I am trying to delete.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger can fire for `0..N` deleted rows.  For example:

```
delete  YourTable
where   1=2
```

Would run a `for delete` trigger on `YourTable`.  So a trigger has to be able to deal with zero or multiple rows.  Consider rewriting your trigger like:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [audit] ON [dbo].[S_PARTY] FOR DELETE
AS
INSERT  dbo.S_AMF_AUDIT_ITEM
        (ROW_ID)   
SELECT  ROW_ID
FROM    deleted
```

That will work for any number of inserted rows.